# Java date object self converting to UTC error

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

Here is my code:

this method is the first entrance of data

```
    private void parseAppAnalytics(JSONObject messageBody, String md5, String messageId) throws JSONException {
    String key = "Events";
    JSONArray appAnalyticsJsonArray = messageBody.getJSONArray(DataSetsConstants.APPANALYTICS);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < appAnalyticsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject appAnalyticsJson = appAnalyticsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        builder.append(messageId).append(COMMA);
        builder.append(md5).append(COMMA);
        builder.append(appAnalyticsJson.optString(DataSetsConstants.APPANALYTICS_GAID, "")).append(COMMA);
        builder.append(appAnalyticsJson.optString(DataSetsConstants.APPANALYTICS_APP_NAME, "")).append(COMMA);
        builder.append(appAnalyticsJson.optString(DataSetsConstants.APPANALYTICS_APP_VERSION, "")).append(COMMA);
        builder.append(appAnalyticsJson.optString(DataSetsConstants.APPANALYTICS_EVENT_NAME, "")).append(COMMA);
        builder.append(getDateFormatter(appAnalyticsJson.optString(DataSetsConstants.APPANALYTICS_EVENT_TIME, ""))).append(COMMA);
        builder.append(messageReceivedTS).append(COMMA);

        logger.debug("***In Parser: parse App Analytics: value: " + builder.toString());
        writeInFile(key, builder.toString());
        builder=new StringBuilder();
    }


}
```

and it comes here:

```
public final String getDateFormatter(String timeinms) {
    try {
        Long l = Long.parseLong(timeinms);
        Date date = new Date(l);
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        String date_time = format.format(date);
        return date_time;
```

When i convert long milliseconds (which is in local time) to date using date object ,it converts the time part to UTC ,this is not expected in my case .I need to stop this conversion.   Is there any thing to do with simpledateformat, am i missing something?

Comment: It's using your default time zone.

Comment: but i am passing the time also through date constructor

Comment: A `java.util.Date` object does not contain timezone information - the object is just a timestamp, and it does not hold any information about a timezone. If you want to display it in a particular timezone, then set the timezone on the `SimpleDateFormat` object. But it would be much better to use the classes in the package `java.time` (Java 8) instead of the old, crappy `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: but the conversion to utc is happening somehow,simpledate format has to do something about this?

Comment: That is probably happening somewhere else in code that you did not show, that is calling the code that you did show.

Comment: What's the value of `timeinms`, the output you're getting and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the long timeinMilliseconds to format() method

```
public final String getDateFormatter(String timeinms) {
try {
    Long l = Long.parseLong(timeinms);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0.00"));//put your timezone here otherwise use "GMT+0.00" for default GMT timezone
    String date_time = format.format(l);
    return date_time;
  }catch(Exception e){

  }
return "";
}
```

Comment: i dont want any time zone convertion , i have to parse time in whatever timezone i have recieved

Comment: @masSdev How do you want to know the time zone from a long value?

Comment: i dont want to know the timezone , i need to stop this conversion to utc for time in millis

Comment: if you dont want any timezone then you can use "GMT+0.00" to get default timezone

Comment: @masSdev This millis value is "the number of milliseconds since epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`)". This number is "absolute" (it's the same everywhere in the world), it's not attached to any timezone. This same number, though, corresponds to a different date and time, depending on the timezone you are. May I ask you to please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46157652/edit) your question and add some examples for the input (the millis value), the expected output and the wrong output you're getting, because (at least to me) it's not clear what you're trying to do and what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity ,i misjudged the milliseconds that i recieved is converted with respect to my timezone ,thank you for your valuable time

Comment: if this answer resolved your issue then don't forget to accept it @masSdev